# Android: Will new threads cause new connection to server, which makes server doesn't record the login info in the new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, network-programming

I want to ask if I use async task to send json for logging in the server, then I jump into another activities and create another async task for getting information which required user logged in. Will the login record lost due to moved to a  new thread, which makes me cannot get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Will the login record lost due to moved to a new thread, 
which makes me cannot get that information?
```

Yes you are correct it will destroy all the data that was in your asynctask because the activity will call `onDestroy` and the **GC**/**Garbage Collector** will be performed thus data is gone.

**solution:**

You need to wait for your `async task to send json for logging in the server` and pass the login information in your `Intent` then use this Intent to jump to another activity. You can [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) on how to pass information using Intent.